# SQL query not showing the right result when using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2018 for my queries and I am trying to get the total quantity of 'Cavity' part types for each order and I have notice some anomaly for 1 order. I am 99% sure that it has been properly added to the SQL database as each order is first created in Access and the .mdb file for this order had 40 'Cavity' parts only. However, when I run an SQL query, I get 248 a total of 248 parts.

So far, I have tried playing around with code, different joins, removing / adding different columns to the SELECT and GROUP BY clause and only filtering out parts using NOT LIKE method helps.

The following code (for 2 orders to show the differences) returns me 2 columns and 2 rows (as expected):

```
SELECT OrderNo, SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders

INNER JOIN Heading ON Orders.OrderID = Heading.OrderID

WHERE ComponentType LIKE 'Cavity' AND OrderNo LIKE '73966' OR OrderNo LIKE '73967'

GROUP BY OrderNo, Quantity
```

However, I get that order 73966 has 40 cavity parts (correct) and that order 73967 has 248 (incorrect).

When I tried changing the query and adding ComponentType (to SELECT and GROUP BY) this is what I got:

```
Order | Quantity | ComponentType
73966    40       Cavity
73967    16       
73967    60       Bead type
73967    40       Cavity
73967    8        Cill
73967    42       Frame
73967    48       Sash
etc...
```

Adding the following helps to filter out the unwanted components but I don't think it should be necessary to get the right results, as adding anything else in the future will force me to update the query.

```
 WHERE (...) AND ComponentType NOT LIKE '%Bead type%'
```

I think it's worth mentioning that both orders have same component types (Bead type, Cavity, Cill) and it's just the order number 73967 not showing properly. Any ideas why I need to filter all other part types for this order manually rather than SQL doing it for me?

Comment: Is Orderno a character column? Why?

Comment: `WHERE ComponentType LIKE 'Cavity' AND OrderNo IN ('73966', '73967')`

Comment: That's how the DB was laid out. OrderNo contains strings and OrderID column contains the primary keys (integers).

Comment: Why `OrderNo LIKE '73966'` at all? Why not `OrderNo = 73966`?

Comment: Also, why are you preforming a `SUM` on `Quantity` and also grouping on it?

Comment: seems you are using the OR clause in wrong way try  use WHERE ComponentType LIKE 'Cavity' AND (  OrderNo LIKE '73966' OR OrderNo LIKE '73967')   .. or as suggested  above use IN clause

Comment: As indicated by the comments, there are a lot of problems with your query that will give you unexpected results.

Comment: Larnu, OrderNo is unfortunately a string and not a number so I cannot use the "=" sign. Regarding grouping the Quantity - my bad. I can see now it was quite a noobish question. I don't know why but I never noticed I'm doing it for one job only (not using "(OrderNo OR OrderNo)"). Thank you for your help guys. @Nick.McDermaid, I would use numbers for OrderNo myself as well but why is using strings not appropriate? What kind of issues could that produce?

Comment: What do you mean you *"can't use the `=` operator"*? Yes you can... `'MyColumn = 'This is a string'` is completely valid SQL... `YourColumn LIKE 'MyString'` is a synonym of `YourColumn = 'MyString'`

Comment: That's what I thought. However, when I try to use it I get an error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '.' to data type int." Okay, I see now I need to use singe quotes as well.

Comment: I guess you're not "ordering" OrderNo, but if you do, it orders as a string, (so 10000000 now comes before 2). Numbers can take less storage. You can use IDENTITY's. It can introduce implicit conversions (which in turn can cause unexpected errors and performance issues). If it's a number, store it as a number not a string. You _can_ use = with strings. as per @jarlh second comment - it's completely valid. In fact there is not much point using `LIKE` if you aren't going to use wildcard as well.

Comment: Because you're storing numerical data as a string, you'd need to do `OrderNo = '73966'`

Comment: `"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '.' to data type int."` is an example of the _implicit conversion causes unexpected errors_ that I referred to in my earlier comment

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful tips and solving the problem so quickly. Now back to learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using  OR clause in wrong way .you need  ()  for check  both OR condition

```
SELECT OrderNo, SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Heading ON Orders.OrderID = Heading.OrderID
WHERE ComponentType LIKE 'Cavity' 
AND  ( OrderNo LIKE '73966' OR OrderNo LIKE '73967')
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

and you should not use column in aggregation function (quantity ) in group  by (in this way the sum fails

anyway if don't use wildchar  then you should use  = and not  like

```
SELECT OrderNo, SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Heading ON Orders.OrderID = Heading.OrderID
WHERE ComponentType =  'Cavity' 
AND  ( OrderNo = '73966' OR OrderNo = '73967')
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

or as suggested  you can use a IN clause for instead fo several  OR

```
SELECT OrderNo, SUM(Quantity) FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Heading ON Orders.OrderID = Heading.OrderID
WHERE ComponentType =  'Cavity' 
AND   OrderNo IN( '73966','73967')
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

Comment: I suggest changing the `LIKE` to `=` for the `OrderNo`, and the `ComponentType LIKE` doesn't do much since there is no wildcard. This answer adresses the `OR`  issue but preserves all the confusion around `LIKE` and string data types

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  correct answer  update for = instead of like when mathcing  string don't contain wildchar ..

Comment: you could also use `IN ('73966', '73967')` instead of `OR`